# Check if button was clicked in PHP from serialize() jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm building a form to allow someone to change the color of buttons, to be used on a webpage, via a web GUI. It's set up to submit the changes via ajax, with jquery, for preview prior to the user clicking the save submit button so they can make sure they like the changes before saving them.

I understand that .serialize() will not send the value of a button click or even tell you that a button was clicked. I have googled and searched stackoverflow but I can't make any of the solutions work with my set up.

**How can the PHP script tell if the save button was clicked?**

HTML:

```
<div id="preview"></div>

<form id="build_form" class="build_form" action="button_preview.php" method="post">
    <input name="color" type="radio" value="red" /> red
    <input name="color" type="radio" value="blue" /> blue
    <input name="save" type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $(".build_form").change(function() {
            $("form").submit();
        });
    });

    $('#build_form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) {
                $('#preview').html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: hi how about adding a hidden input that gets updated when the color is changed, and by serializing you will still get that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.submit()` on the form and then handling the submit event to stop the default submit and do an Ajax call seems overly complicated even aside from the fact that it stops your Save button working. Why not do the Ajax preview part directly in the change event and leave the submit to happen naturally via the Save button (which is a submit button already)? Remove the submit handler entirely.

```
$(function() {
    $("#build_form").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            success: function(response) {
                $('#preview').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When the Save button is clicked the request will include a parameter `save` with value `Save`, so in your PHP you can test for that. When the request is made via Ajax the parameter `save` will not be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden input that gets updated when you change your color value, this will have the effect of being `serialize()`able

***edit***
i see i didt address your point, why not add an `onclick` on your button that calls the function when clicked?